# Converting dd/mm/yyyy formatted string to Datetime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I am new to DotNet and C#. I want to convert a string in `mm/dd/yyyy` format to `DateTime` object. I tried the parse function like below but it is throwing a runtime error.

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.Parse("24/01/2013");
```

Any ideas on how may I convert it to datetime?

Answer (score 309, accepted):

You need to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) with format `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Its safer if you use `d/M/yyyy` for the format, since that will handle both single digit and double digits day/month. But that really depends if you are expecting single/double digit values.

---

Your date  format `day/Month/Year` might be an acceptable date format for some cultures. For example for Canadian Culture `en-CA` `DateTime.Parse` would work like:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("24/01/2013", new CultureInfo("en-CA"));
```

Or

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("24/01/2013"); //uses the current Thread's culture
```

Both the above lines would work because the the string's format is acceptable for `en-CA` culture. Since you are not supplying any culture to your `DateTime.Parse` call, your current culture is used for parsing which doesn't support the date format. Read more about it at [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Another method for parsing is using [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("24/01/2013", 
                            "d/M/yyyy", 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            DateTimeStyles.None,
    out dt))
{
    //valid date
}
else
{
    //invalid date
}
```

The `TryParse` group of methods in .Net framework doesn't throw exception on invalid values, instead they return a `bool` value indicating success or failure in parsing.

**Notice** that I have used single `d` and `M` for day and month respectively. Single `d` and `M` works for both single/double digits day and month. So for the format `d/M/yyyy` valid values could be:

- "24/01/2013"
- "24/1/2013"
- "4/12/2013" //4 December 2013
- "04/12/2013"

For further reading you should see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had already tried the DateTime.ParseExact() but I guess the trick was with the null as third argument. I was using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture instead which would give me a compilation error.

Comment: @user1872530, you are welcome, it should have worked for you, but I guess you are missing using statement for System.Globalization, so try `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead,

Comment: Thanks. I was using "dd/MM/yyyy" and the parse failed for "3/12/2016" changing it to "d/M/yyyy" worked as the day and month values < 10 no longer need to be prepended with zero.

Comment: if the string includes the time, "dd/M/yyyy H:mm:ss" can be used

Answer (score 22):

use `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
string strDate = "24/01/2013";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null)
```

- [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

`null` will use the current culture, which is somewhat dangerous. Try to supply a specific culture

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: You should use "dd/MM/yyyy" instead of "dd/MM/YYYY".

Answer (score 9):

You can use `"dd/MM/yyyy"` format for using it in [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/UjZzVB).

For more informations, check out [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)