# How to parse date format of d/y/year?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to know how to convert string that my contains for example the string maybe (`1/1/2015`) or (`14/1/2015`) or (`14/11/2015`) and convert to a date

```
string mydate;
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Is this right way?

Comment: which language? java or C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting dd/mm/yyyy formatted string to Datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738608/converting-dd-mm-yyyy-formatted-string-to-datetime)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: I am using C# 
I know there is other Posts to convert string to Datetime but they are talking about converting string like (dd/mm/yyyy) is it the same for string contains string like (d/m/yyyy) like (1/1/2015)

Comment: Hi @Saleh923, The main difference between "d/m/yyyy" & "dd/mm/yyyy" is month/day numbers without/with leading zeroes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since neither your days nor months have a [leading zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero) for single digits, you need to use `d/M/yyyy` format instead.

```
string mydate;
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will successfully parse all three kind strings that you have.

Further reading:

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Saleh923 Yes, try and see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateFormat outputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa");
Date date = null;

try
{
    date = df.parse(listData.get(position).get("datetime"));
    strDateTime = outputformat.format(date);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you need the output like this --> **1/1/2015**

> just change the formatted method d/m/yyyy

```
 DateFormat outputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("d/m/yyyy");
```

> All the date format, visit this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: aa means AM/PM comes if you write "aa".

Comment: Based on OP's example, it is `c#`.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can try the below code :-

```
 String str_date="14/1/2015";
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 Date date = formatter.parse(str_date);
```

Here's an link of relevance from [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), listing all available format patterns:

Comment: Based on OP's example, it is `c#`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use SimpleDateFormat for parsing between Date and String.

```
String strDate = "2013-05-15T10:00:00-0700";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Based on OP's example, it is `c#`.