# String format with c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime-format

I have this string value

```
var d = "2016-01-07 09"
```

It's a string that contains a date with hour without minutes, seconds and millis.
I want to trasform into Datetime with this format

```
2016-01-07 09:00:00:000
```

I know that it sounds stupid but this stuff makes me crazy.
Thanks for support.

Comment: Did you try searching, and perhaps come along [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx)? Or did you do that, and are you having trouble converting the `DateTime` to a string in this specific format? Please read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Comment: And while there are better ways, `+ ":00:00:000"` is also a solution.

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this question, suggest you improve your Google fu.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738608/converting-dd-mm-yyyy-formatted-string-to-datetime

Comment: Is that date supposed to be Jan. 7th or July 1st? It could be parsed either way you do realize, right?

Comment: @JBKing - the whole purpose for year-in-front is to solve that issue. Anyone formatting a July date this way should not be allowed near a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Date with format  Year - Month - Day Hour (yyyy-MM-dd HH).

You can use DateTime ParseExact method . If you know your dates format. You can parse it .

Check dateformats on  [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 string d= "2016-01-08 03";
 var c = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return c;
```

Comment: Please explain what the code in your answer does.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have added, thanks