# Convert a string format to formated date style

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, string, date

I use asp.net, I have a string format "01/29/2016". How I can format this string to "29/01/2016" output?. Because that value will be processed on report filtering,

Thank You,

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15738608/3883460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your string format to date time. use following

```
DateTime YourDate= DateTime.ParseExact(
            "01/29/2016",
            "MM/dd/yyyy",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And then convert this date time to your required format.

```
string myDateString = YourDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a date value you can use
Date.toString (dd/MM/yyyy)
If not do a convertion of the string beforehand with
DateTime.Parse (string)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ParseExact (myString, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString (@"dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This should do the trick for you