# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime C# Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have date in string format `20/05/2016`:

```
string weekEndDate="20/05/2016"
```

when convert it to DateTime,An error Occured:

```
DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(weekEndDate);
```

**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: What is the culture on your server. Is it one that accepts dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting dd/mm/yyyy formatted string to Datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738608/converting-dd-mm-yyyy-formatted-string-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your string format to "yyyy-mm-dd" or "yyyy/mm/dd"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DateTime.TryParse` method to parse date from any date format. See [examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-tryparse)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParseExact` method to parse the string into `DateTime`.

```
string weekEndDate = "20/05/2016";
DateTime EndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(weekEndDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or you can use `TryParseExact` it will not throw `exception` if `string` is not parsed into `DateTime`

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(weekEndDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out EndDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TryParseExact

```
string d1 = "11/18/2016 11:45:44 AM";
string d2 = "11/18/2016 11:45:59 AM";

DateTime frmdate;
DateTime todate;
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
bool f = DateTime.TryParseExact(d1, "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out frmdate);
bool t = DateTime.TryParseExact(d2, "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out todate);

TimeSpan val = frmdate - todate;
```