# How to convert a Textbox String to a Datetime in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How can I convert a textbox string to datetime in asp.net c#  ?

I tried this:

```
DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(tbx_Created.Text);
string createdformatted = d2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
DateTime CreatdDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tbx_Created.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it shows this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I have given 15-6-2016 to textbox.

Please advise.

Comment: Food for thought: `I have given 15-6-2016 to textbox`, `DateTime.ParseExact(..., "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")` notice something?

Comment: you are passing a date but trying to parse a time as well, remove everything except `MM/dd/yyyy`.. I'm guessing this is what @Manfred pointed out as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can parse user input like this:

```
DateTime enteredDate = DateTime.Parse(enteredString);
```

If you have a specific format for the string, you should use the other method:

```
DateTime loadedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(loadedString, "d", null);
```

Your formats input should match the Exact:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15738613/6460963)

Answer (score 1):

For `"15-6-2016"` input, datetime pattern should be `"d-M-yyyy"`

```
   DateTime CreatdDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tbx_Created.Text, 
     "d-M-yyyy", 
     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can try apply *several* patterns in one go, like this:

```
   DateTime CreatdDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tbx_Created.Text, 
     new String[] {
       "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", // your initial pattern, recommended way
       "d-M-yyyy"},              // actual input, tolerated way
     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
     DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `MM` for month while value of month is `6` not `06` so you need to use `M` for month.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime.TryParseExact(tbx_Created.Text, "dd-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime CreatdDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tbx_Created.Text, "d-M-yyyy", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse with exact format using [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx). But before parsing check if it is parsing will be valid using [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact("15-6-2016", "dd-M-yyyy",null))
{
    myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("15-6-2016", "dd-M-yyyy", null);
    Console.WriteLine(myDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime d2= DateTime.Parse(tbx_Created.Text);
```

A better way would be this:

```
DateTime d2;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(tbx_Created.Text, out myDate))
{
    // handle parse failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(txbx_created.Text);
String CurrentTime = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}", datetime);
```