# Whenever choose date from Datepicker date and month position is changing

Tags: c#

Whenever  i choose the date from datepicker the date will flip with month position.

i tried to convert the date format from dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy and reverse also but the selected date is flipping the date to month.

```
$(function () {

    $("#<%= txtDatePicker.ClientID %>").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy"
    });

    $("#<%= txtDatePicker1.ClientID %>").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy"
    });
});
```

C# code is

```
  var dateAndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatePicker.Text);
            var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

Or 
try to converted to string and change the format

```html
string d1 =txtDatePicker.Text;
d1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyyy")
```

nothing helps.

if i want to choose the date between 01-Aug-2019 and second date 29-Sep-2019.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParseExact` to convert date from specific format. Suppose you are getting date as `dd/MM/yyyy` then

`DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDatePicker.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null)`

For more info [Converting dd/mm/yyyy formatted string to Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738608/converting-dd-mm-yyyy-formatted-string-to-datetime/15738613)